# how to add data from sql to JTable in same line?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jtable

iam trying to add my data from DB to JTable in java ( using eclipse ) , so the data inserted in different rows ,but i need to add these data in same line until my column filled then go to the next line .

```
while(r.next()){

        String itemCode = r.getString("item_name"); 
        TableModel2.addRow(new Object[]{itemCode});

}
```

[image: image for clarification my problem]

i try to use setValueAt but my code not working right ..

```
while(r.next()){

      for (int index =0 ; index < TableModel2.getColumnCount(); index ++){
        for (int i =0 ; index < TableModel2.getColumnCount(); index ++){
            String itemCode = r.getString("item_name"); 
            table_3.setValueAt((Object)itemCode,i, index);
       }}}
```

[image: image for clarification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
int i = 1;
java.util.List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
while(r.next()){
    items.add(r.getString("item_name")); // Add all items to List
    if(i >= 3){
         TableModel2.addRow(items.toArray(new String[items.size()])); // Convert the List to array and add it to the row
         items = new ArrayList<String>();
         i = 1;
    }
    i++;
}
if(items.size()>0)
   TableModel2.addRow(items.toArray(new String[items.size()])); // Adding the rest items to the last row.
```

Comment: thank you , but in `[list.size()]`  did you mean in list = List ? when i wrote it in this way `[List.size()]` i got error : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method size() from the type List . and if i replace it by `[items.size()]` it working well but just fills first row(line) i mean it not continue to next line with other items . THANK YOU

Comment: @sara .. I have also updated the answer to add the rest items to the last row. GoodLuck and don't forget to upvote the answer, when you find it useful ;)

Comment: done ;) , also i need help from you in other problem in my project if you can and if you have time , am not sure if i can ask another question here because i was asked recently , saly-2010-@hotmail.com

Comment: Don't worry just ask as many questions as you like, we do not need to contact via email. However, I will send you an email :)